# Is always a copy made when a return value is assigned to a variable?

Tags: c#, variable-assignment

The [C# language reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#assignment-operators) claims that

> An assignment always performs a simple bit-wise copy of a value into a
> variable.

<s>This is certainly not true for assignments of the form `int i = 7;` and I guess also that only one instance is created in `A a = new A(...);`.</s> I am wondering whether the assignment of the return value of a method to a variable is always a copy of the return value (not talking about `ref returns`). A local variable that is returned could be safely reused, since otherwise it would be collected by the GC anyways without being used ever again after the method call.

Example Code:

```
struct A {
    public int f() {
       int j = 7;
       return j;
    }

    public int g(out int j) {
       return j = 7;
    }
}

A a = new A();
int jj = a.f(); // Are j and jj aliases?
int jjj;
a.g(out jjj); // j and jjj are aliases
```

Comment: "This is certainly not true for assignments of the form `int i = 7;`" Umm... But it is? Can you show why you think it is not true?

Comment: `Are j and jj aliases?` No.

Comment: `7` is not a predefined variable that is copied to `i`. `i` is simply set to the value `7`, without copying another variable.

Comment: How does that contradict `An assignment always performs a simple bit-wise copy of a value into a variable.`? _Given 7 is a value._

Comment: `So you claim that in that assignment two ints with value 7 are created?` https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyDMABGgQMIEDeOB1RhyALAQLIAUAlBVTd2AHbAEAVgQC8BAOwBuLtQC+OWUA=

Comment: `What about A a = new A()?`https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyDMABGgQMIEDeOB1RhyALAQLIAUAlBVTd2AHbAEAVgQC8BAOwBuLt2p8BAa1FDp2WTRmyAggQCGy3gFMA7gS3tV3AL44b2HPiKoznNTUfyCAIwD2XigDmhsCSBADOwZJ2VkA=

Comment: `A local variable that is returned could be safely reused,` The local variable could be used by a `Task.Run` initiated by the function - is one example why it would not be _necessarily_ safe to reuse.

Comment: @mjwills Thanks for convincing me of the opposite. I did not consider `7` to be a value, which would have been clear in an expression like `8-1`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What gets copied / popped and why depends on what you do with them, you can easily figure it out for yourself.

<sub>***Note** : .Net specs only has *by value* and *by ref* and  `out`, is just by `ref`. So as you can see this all just makes sense as per the documentation*.</sub>

```
struct A
{
   public unsafe int f()
   {
      int j = 7;
      Console.WriteLine($"j1 \t: {(uint) &j}");
      return j;
   }

   public unsafe int g(out int j)
   {
      j = 7;
      fixed (int* p = &j)
         Console.WriteLine($"j2 \t: {(uint) p}");
      return j;
   }
}

public static unsafe void Main()
{

   A a = new A();
   int jj = a.f(); // Are j and jj aliases?
   Console.WriteLine($"jj \t: {(uint) &jj}");
   int jjj;
   var jjjj = a.g(out jjj); // j and jjj are aliases
   Console.WriteLine($"jjj \t: {(uint) &jjj}");
   Console.WriteLine($"jjjj \t: {(uint) &jjjj}");
}
```

**Output**

```
j1      : 2654464036
jj      : 2654464172
j2      : 2654464160
jjj     : 2654464160
jjjj    : 2654464156
```

<sub>***Note 2** : You could also use [Sharp IO](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYGYAE9MGFMDeqmJmAzsAE4CuAxsJgIKHGkaZgB2DAZgBQBKFilKiuDAFaYAvJgDsAblajsczBKUjSAX1TLsWcZgDmfAPbUGRiUKJaVMNVNmL9ulO/3sYAFkwBZQWEVUlRmAEMZTE4AUwB3JkFNa2dMcIA6fgEFTAB6XKZKGPU0zgATdSlwiDBwshiyAH5UFI1UDNMLSQkbHPyS8PLKqqK0mrqGt1RtIA) to see what's actually happening a little more clearly, [example here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYGYAE9MGFMDeqmJmAzsAE4CuAxsJgIKHGkaZgB2DAZgBQBKFilKiuDAFaYAvJgDsAblajsczBKUjSAX1TLsWcZgDmfAPbUGRiUKJaVMNVNmL9ulO/3sYAFkwBZQWEVUlRmAEMZTE4AUwB3JkFNa2dMcIA6fgEFTAB6XKZKGPU0zgATdSlwiDBwshiyAH5UFI1UDNMLSQkbHPyS8PLKqqK0mrqGt1RtIA)*.</sub>